# Okta - The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: c#, okta-api

I have set up an Okta dev site and I am trying to connect to it through a .NET app.

I have set up the .NET app as instructed through the Okta SDK, creating the token etc., and I am trying to run the following code from the SDK

```
// OktaClient is a convenience client to create other clients
var oktaClient = new OktaClient("your api token", "your production subdomain");
var usersClient = oktaClient.GetUsersClient();

// Retrieve a user
user = usersClient.Get("user@example.com");
```

I get the following error "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure" on the Get command.

Does anyone know what else I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not using the "right" OktaClient constructor.

The one you seem to be using works well for *.okta.com tenants. For *.oktapreview.com tenants, you should use the following constructor instead:

```
var oktaClient = new OktaClient(apiKey, new Uri(tenantUrl));
```

where tenantUrl is the full url of your Okta dev tenant (such as "https://dev-XXXXX.oktapreview.com").

I hope this helps,

Raphael.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your Okta URL is incorrect. Your Okta org URL should look similar to `https://org.okta.com` or `https://dev-1234.oktapreview.com`.

Some typos I've seen cause this error are:

- `https://dev-1234.com` (missing the `okta.com` or `oktapreview.com` domain)
- `https://dev-1234.oktapreview.com.com` (duplicated suffix)